# Webex webhooks locale?

Tags: webex

I'm trying to develop a bot for Webex.
The documentation recommends using the Webhooks.

It looks easy to implement, the only missing piece is the language of the user.

With Microsoft Teams, I have access to a "locale" attribute inside the payload corresponding to the user's Teams app language.
Inside the Webex webhooks payload, I don't have any information about the user "language"/app locale.

Do you have any idea how to get that info, so my bot can determine what language the user is speaking?

Thanks